# how to find a memory leak in a manager nodelet in indigo

Tags: nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

PID          %CPU   %MEM        VIRT                   RSS
8961      153        1.2         1979600              198448  ?             Ssl          12-Feb   2273:44:00               /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet         manager              __name:=kinect2tnl_cam1               __log:=/home/mpatalberta/.ros/log/e27c5f9e-d19e-11e5-81af-c03fd563536f/kinect2tnl_cam1-1.log   0                 9420
8961      150        1.2         1979600              207868  ?             Ssl          12-Feb   10703:12               /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet         manager              __name:=kinect2tnl_cam1               __log:=/home/mpatalberta/.ros/log/e27c5f9e-d19e-11e5-81af-c03fd563536f/kinect2tnl_cam1-1.log

The nodelet leaks  207868 - 198449 = 9040

How do I find the memory leak in the kinect2tnl_cam1-1 process?

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227041/how-to-find-a-memory-leak-in-a-manager-nodelet-in-indigo/) by [mpatalberta](https://answers.ros.org/users/23552/mpatalberta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Compiling as DEBUG and running the nodelet manager with an additional

```
launch-prefix="valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes --track-origins=yes --log-file=YOUR_LOG_FILE_PATH_AND_NAME_HERE"
```

where it is launched in a launch file worked well for me before.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1